# How to allow Typescript Generic parameter to have default

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to set a default for a generic function in TS. Here is a simplistic example:

```js
type Size = "small" | "medium" | "large";
type Detail<S extends Size> = S extends "small" ? "noDetail" : S extends "medium" ? "partialDetail" : "fullDetail"

function getDetail<S extends Size>(size:S = "small"):Detail<S>{
    if(size === "small")
        return "noDetail" as Detail<S>;
    if(size === "medium")
        return "partialDetail" as Detail<S>
    return "fullDetail" as Detail<S>;
}
```

It causes the error:

```
Type '"small"' is not assignable to type 'S'.
  '"small"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'S', but 'S' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Size'.ts(2322)
```

I understand the problem (ex: someone could try `getDetail<"large">();` ) and I've read several posts on SO to try and resolve.

However,

1. I don't want to force people to pass a parameter.
2. I want to return the conditional type (not unconstrained string, not union)

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is better done with function overloads

```
function getDetail(): Detail<"small">;
function getDetail<T extends Size>(size: T): Detail<T>;
function getDetail(size: Size = "small"): Detail<Size>{
    if(size === "small")
        return "noDetail";
    if(size === "medium")
        return "partialDetail";
    return "fullDetail";
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgL2gXigIgM4FsCGAbPNKAH3SwgBM4BXLI0tPHAJwHMI0BuAKFEigAiEYDjh4APDCgQAHsAgA7ChliIIAPiiops+UpWZcBIgH50CgPZCRYogC5Y0uYuVlKNOlDNowLYHHxrUUIoBzQAM2oCINtubkiFAGN-CwUodmAYvAAKAEoHLPFDfEJ1eOoklLSMwoAVJz1XeCR1bIw1B1r8wWFg8VqyhOS4VPThLLaO1SQtdGwStG7C5o0Ab24oTag4cMmZ5AO5o0Jcja3z5mFqZjS0SyyuM82dvZRDtHIqWkWn86hL4DXW6+Zj+QK9Ww8C5XG7oSLRCGEHgAXyAA)

Comment: I just tried it and that appears to work. fantastic solution; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would add `"small"` as type for `size` and I would also add `"small"` as default for the generic type.

```
function getDetail<S extends Size = "small">(size: S | "small" = "small"):Detail<S>{
    if(size === "small")
        return "noDetail" as Detail<S>;
    if(size === "medium")
        return "partialDetail" as Detail<S>
    return "fullDetail" as Detail<S>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgL2gXigIgM4FsCGAbPNKAH3SwgBM4BXLI0tPHAJwHMI0BuAWAChRIUACIRgOOHgA8MKBAAewCADsKGWIggA%20KKhnzFKtZlwEiAfnRKA9iLESiALliyFy1WUo06UC2jAtgOHxbcUIoJzQAM2oCEPs%20PmilAGNAqyUodmA4qT1XQ3UkHXRsfEJNAAoMDScZBlLTYuMytABKBxzpTQBvPih%20qDhIqo0dZFRm01a%20gdnmUWpmDLRrHKIcNU6YTR5eWaGRovGJ8ipaNpnZ-vngReX-ZkDg0VD1zZeJLsuoG7v0aNiHzCG2EQK6uwAvgleMl0hhgFAcMUsp00KcvGhKtMYXCEQAjZGiHIVVpAA)

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I think I expected this would cause the result to become a union, but your solution returns the correct type without the union. Thank you!

In case others come to this: the one disadvantage to this approach is that it does permit some bad behavior:

`const a = getDetail<"medium">("small"); // no error and results 'partialDetail'`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Enum with your different values and then create your function based on that. As you requested the return as a conditional type, i also added an Interface so the return is typesafe:

```
enum Size {
   "small",
   "medium",
   "large"
}
interface Detail<Size> {
    model: string
}

function getDetail(size:Size = Size.small){
    return {
        model: Size[size]
    } as Detail<typeof size>;
}

console.log(getDetail(Size.medium));
console.log(getDetail());
```